# .twilio-cli/node_modules/@k88/typescript-compile-error-formatter/dist/

Tags: twilio, twilio-cli

I got an error when I built a typewritten code with an error. I have developed a Twilio plugin. After resaving, nothing changed, the error was also in the console and it was necessary to restart the run command

Want to share here to save someone time

> .twilio-cli/node_modules/@k88/typescript-compile-error-formatter/dist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated twilio-cli (@twilio-labs/plugin-flex) from **4.3.0** -> **4.3.4** and everything started working

[Instructions for updating](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/cli/upgrade)